# Online or email heads or tails coin flip for two people

Tags: email, notifications

In the case that two people agree that they would accept the result of a coin flip to resolve some dispute.

Is there a virtual heads or tails flip of a coin system that could be done online by two people, preferably with email notifications of the result for both participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices come to mind:

- [Random.org coin flipper](http://www.random.org/coins/) (they also offer a [Third-party draw service](http://www.random.org/draws/) that could be useful for you.  This service offers true random numbers.)
- [Flip a Coin Online](http://www.flipacoinonline.com/) (this site gives no information on the random number generation algorithim used.)

Answer (score 0):

I like this answer [from Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-flip-a-coin-with-someone-over-the-internet):

> Currently, the way I've been doing it is by generating two MD5
>   checksums of "heads+" and "tails+" and
>   giving the two checksums to the other person. They pick one and then I
>   disclose both phrases so they can verify which side was chosen.